# Prevent thin spaces to widen when paragraph is justified in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment, space

How can I prevent thin spaces' widening when included in a justified paragraph in Microsoft Word? This is important to me because I must use thin spaces to separate thousands, following the standards by ISO 80000-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Word 2016 onward, this is no longer an issue; however, in previous versions like 2010 it is.

The problem can be solved by replacing each THIN SPACE by a NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F). Use Find and Replace to handle many substitutions.

In most fonts, NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE and THIN SPACE are equal (Times New Roman, Palatino Linotype, Arial, Cambria) or almost equal (Calibri). An exception is Segoe UI.